# Python trying to randomly select the value from list within a list results in the TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random, password-generator

I tried to search a lot but could not find proper resolution hence posting here.
I am new to Python and I am trying to create a simple password generator application which is of 8 characters and should consist of 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 special character, and 1 numeric values. I am able to get these things and create a 4 letter password with Uppercase, lowercase, special character, and numeric values. For the remaining 4 characters, I want to choose the options randomly from the list which is made up of all these options but for some reason, I am unable to obtain the values randomly for it. I am getting the following error when I try to access the random choice from the list within a list:

`TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 4`

I wanted to know how can I select a random value which can be either lowercase, uppercase, numeric or special characters for the remaining 4 values in my final password. I know I can use the `for` loop to accomplish the same but I would like to do it randomly so I am trying this approach.

Following is the code I have so far and some of the things I have tried to obtain the random values located list within a list:

```
import random
import string

def passwordGenerator():
    lowerchars      =   list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    upperchars      =   list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    speciachars     =   ['&','!','_','@']
    numericchars    =   list(range(0,9))
    otherrandom     =   list(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase, range(0,9), ['&','!','_','@'])
    #otherrandom     =   list(list(string.ascii_lowercase), list(string.ascii_uppercase) list(range(0,9)), ['&','!','_','@'])
    print(random.choice(otherrandom))
    #print(random.choice(random.choice(otherrandom)))
    password        = random.choice(lowerchars) + random.choice(upperchars) + random.choice(speciachars) + str(random.choice(numericchars))

passwordGenerator()
```

Comment: It seems like you are aiming for this: `otherrandom  =   lowerchars + upperchars + numericchars + speciachars`

Comment: Yup, that what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list() method only takes one argument.
You can do

```
otherrandom = lowerchars + upperchars + numericchars + speciachars
```

This adds all of the lists together, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Yup, that what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)